# Weird GUDHI + rpy2 interaction

Tags: python, r, rpy2

This might be a pretty niche problem but I've come across it and found a solution which maybe will help someone eventually. Basically, I'm trying to call the GUDHI C++ library through R using rpy2 using the following code:

```
import gudhi
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
import rpy2.robjects.vectors as rvectors
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
import numpy as np


point_cloud = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(30, 3))
# tda.point_cloud_to_pl(point_cloud, method="GUDHI_R")
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

# import R's "base" package
base = rpackages.importr('base')

# import R's "utils" package
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')

# select a mirror for R packages
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list

# R package names
packnames = ('TDA', 'deldir', 'Matrix', 'SparseM')
names_to_install = [x for x in packnames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]
if len(names_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(rvectors.StrVector(names_to_install))

# Importing packages
rpackages.importr('TDA')
rpackages.importr('deldir')
rpackages.importr('Matrix')
rpackages.importr('SparseM')

X = robjects.r.assign("X", point_cloud)
alpha_complex_diag = robjects.r['alphaComplexDiag']
ph_output = alpha_complex_diag(X)
print(ph_output)
```

But keep getting a segmentation fault error saying

```
 *** caught segfault ***

R[write to console]: address 0x7fa6ac2c6090, cause 'invalid permissions'
```

The solution is to remove the `import gudhi` at the top of the python script. For some reason that causes R to not be able to use it? Perhaps because they are trying to call the same library?

Answer (score 1):

It may indeed be a conflict between dynamically loaded libraries used by both Python and R. One such example is scipy doing what seems odd things with BLAS, and this causes a crash: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/505

I do not know GUDHI at all unfortunately. If this is a blocker you'd need to run this through a debugger to find what it is happening in the C library.